# How to exclude columns in Access VBA to maintain data

Tags: ms-access

I have a Access form with a bunch of buttons and some text boxes.
The text boxes automatically fill to the table. Thanks to someone else on here I figured out how to sync the button press to the fill the table. Now I need to ensure that the rest of information in the table stays when I press the button and the "Yes" get recorded. Currently all the other column of information doesnt record to the sheet but the button press does. How do I pass by those columns and keep their data and still record the various button presses that need to happen?

Thanks in advance!!

Below is the current button code that records on the table.

```
Private Sub CWTButton_Click()

Dim Sql As String

Sql = "INSERT INTO [Raw Data] (CWT) VALUES ('Yes');"
CurrentDb.Execute Sql

End Sub`
```

New Code

```
Private Sub CWTButton_Click()

Dim Sql As String

Sql = "INSERT INTO [RawData] ([Date], Staff, Species, Location, Length, Fish_ID, Comment, CWT) VALUES ('" & Me!Date.Value & "', '" & Me!Staff.Value & "', '" & Me!Species.Value & "', '" & Me!Location.Value & "', '" & Me!Length.Value & "', '" & Me!Fish_ID.Value & "','" & Me!Comment.Value & "','Yes');"
CurrentDb.Execute Sql
```

End Sub

Comment: If you have a bound form, why are you using INSERT action? Just populate field: `Me.CWT = "Yes"`. Is CWT a Yes/No type field?

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to update a record rather than "INSERT".  if that is the case use the "UPDATE" sql statement.  If you are inserting a new record with the same fields as on the form and CWT selected then you must include all the fields in the insert statement.  Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109270/how-to-use-vba-to-add-new-record-in-ms-access

Comment: @June7 The form is definitely unbound. In design view the boxes say unbound.

Comment: Then textboxes cannot "automatically fill the table" - only bound form/controls can do that. Why not use bound form/controls?

Comment: @June7 Yes pardon my ignorance. I meant there is already code that is filling those values into the table from the form.

Comment: @Mazoula You were right I just needed to insert all of the fields into the INSERT statement. Another user helped me that. I updated my original post. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then what exactly is the issue now? If [Date] is a date/time field, its input should be delimited with # not apostrophe. Number type field would not use any delimiter. Advise not to use reserved words like Date as field names. Not necessary to type .Value as that is default property of data controls. Use dot instead of bang (!) for referencing controls.

Comment: @June7 The data is getting to the table correctly without deleting the other records. Though I understand if I have a bunch of buttons doing this with the same commands, it is making a bunch of different records. I don't necessarily want 10 different records for the same data set, only one. Is there a way where This buttons can be recorded and save to the table all at once?

Comment: I don't understand why you are not using a bound form and bound controls. After record is committed to table with INSERT, use UPDATE to modify its data. Will need the ID of that saved record.

Comment: @June7 I am trying to build on top of an already built form. I don't have a ton of experience nor time to make this form work.

Comment: You already partly answered your own question. Cannot have multiple buttons with same code creating record. Should have textboxes or comboboxes for user input/selection of data then one button that creates record. Or go to a bound form/controls.

Comment: @June7 Alright yep, that makes sense. Guess I'll fuck around with trying to a build a bound form or more comboboxes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Code

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO [RawData] ([Date], Staff, Species, Location, Length, Fish_ID, Comment, CWT) VALUES (#" & Format(Me!Date.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd" & "#', '" & Me!Staff.Value & "', '" & Me!Species.Value & "', '" & Me!Location.Value & "', " & Me!Length.Value & ", " & Me!Fish_ID.Value & ",'" & Me!Comment.Value & "','Yes');"
```